# Insert blank spaces in txt file - Python

Tags: python-3.x, insert, text-files

I have a txt file with thousand of rows.
Almost all of the rows have the same length of 180 characters but some of the rows are shorter than 180.
I need to add blank spaces to these shorter rows in order to make all of the rows in the text file of the same 180 characters length

```
filename = "text.txt"
numLines = 0

with open(filename, 'r+') as file:
    for line in file:
        if len(line) != 180:
            emptySpaces = (180 - len(line))

        numLines += 1
```

I tried to use the insert method  but without success.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```py
import fileinput

filename = "text.txt"

for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
    line = line.strip("\n")
    if len(line) != 180:
        emptySpaces = " " * (180 - len(line))
    else:
        emptySpaces = ""

    print("{}{}".format(line, emptySpaces), end="\n")
```

This replaces every line in the file by the new line `"{}{}".format(line, emptySpaces)`.